# Random timeouts when using SE main sites and *.chat.SE

Tags: bug, chat, 408-timeout

I'm having random issues, like "Connection was reset" and "Timeouts" when trying to access the different pages of SE and when posting in chat. It's difficult to nail the exact problem because it works fine until it doesn't and then starts working fine again.

I've noticed that as a general symptom whenever this is about to occur, the page loads slower and chat becomes unresponsive for a while. In the case of chat sometimes the message gets sent *and* timeouts which results in double posting in cases where you click "retry".

This isn't an issue with other sites I browse, nor specific to the browser itself, tried Firefox, Chromium stable, and [bjb568 on Safari](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2332280#2332280) and the issue keeps happening.